# Troubleshooting running celery worker with supervisor for Django app

Tags: django, redis, django-admin, celery, supervisord

I have a Django app, where I aim to run a task via celery via redis.

The project folder structure is as follows:

```
/mhb11/myfolder/myproject
├── myproject
│   ├── celery.py       # The Celery app file
│   ├── __init__.py     # The project module file (modified)
│   ├── settings.py     # Including Celery settings
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── celerybeat-schedule
└── myapp
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tasks.py        # File containing tasks for this app
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

I have `celery.conf` in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` which contains:

```
[program:celery]
command=/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery --app=myproject.celery:app worker -l info
command=/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery --app=myproject.celery:app beat -l info
directory = /home/mhb11/myfolder/myproject
user=mhb11
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile = /etc/supervisor/logs/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile = /etc/supervisor/logs/celery-worker.log
autostart = true
autorestart = true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup = true
priority = 998
```

And in `/etc/supervisor/logs`, I have an empty file called `celery-worker.log`. After setting this up, I ran the following commands:

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
```

After doing this, my celery workers are supposed to start, yet they don't. I.e. nothing shows up in the `celery-worker.log` file I set up. I don't know what I'm missing, since it's my first time setting all of this up. Can you help troubleshoot this for me?

---

`djcelery` is part of INSTALLED_APPS. Moreover, other relevant settings in `settings.py` are:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'redis'

CELERY_IMPORTS = ('myapp.tasks', )  

CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT=True

from datetime import timedelta

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'

# CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
#   'tasks.rank_all_photos': {
#       'task': 'tasks.rank_all_photos',
#       'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
#   },
# }

CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

My `celery.py` contains:

```
#this is the celery daemon
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

app = Celery('myapp', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0',include=['myfolder.myapp.tasks'])
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS) 

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

`__init__.py` contains:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app1
```

`tasks.py` contains:

```
import os
from myproject import celery_app1
import time
from myapp.models import Photo

@celery_app1.task(name='tasks.rank_all_photos')
def rank_all_photos():
    for photo in Photo.objects.order_by('-id')[:400]:
        photo.set_rank()
```

Lastly, in my Django admin panel, I've also set up a `crontab` and a `periodic task`.

What should I do to get everything started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running your worker, workers are only to execute tasks, but tasks needs to be put in the queue for workers to find tasks. Celery beat puts the tasks in the queue according the the schedule set via Django Admin or from a schedules file. After beat queue's the task, workers find it and execute it.

So you need to run a celery beat process separately. A separate supervisor process with

```
command=/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery --app=myproject.celery:app beat -l info
```

Celery beat is needed when you are using periodic/schedules tasks. If you are only manually queuing the tasks by calling task's `.delay()` method then you don't need Celery beat to be running.

So your 2 supervisor files will be

**beat**

```
[program:celerybeat]
command=/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery --app=myproject.celery:app beat -l info
directory = /home/mhb11/myfolder/myproject
user=mhb11
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile = /etc/supervisor/logs/celery-beat.log
stderr_logfile = /etc/supervisor/logs/celery-beatlog
autostart = true
autorestart = true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup = true
priority = 998
```

**worker**

```
[program:celeryworker]
command=/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery --app=myproject.celery:app worker -l info
directory = /home/mhb11/myfolder/myproject
user=mhb11
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile = /etc/supervisor/logs/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile = /etc/supervisor/logs/celery-worker.log
autostart = true
autorestart = true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup = true
priority = 998
```

Comment: Yep the tasks are periodic. I'll try this and get back to you. Thanks for helping out and clearing the concept Tahir :-)

Comment: tried it (updated the `conf.d` file in the question too so you know how it looks like now), yet nothing shows up in my logs. Any other leads, since this didn't work? p.s. I `reread` and `updated` afterwards too.

Comment: @HassanBaig you need to create 2 separate process via supervisor. It will take 2 separate supervisor files. I have added both the files to answer.

Comment: yes I realized that, hence accepted your answer. I'm now stuck at the next step (and posted a question for that on SO): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363393/running-supervisord-from-the-host-celery-from-a-virtualenv-django-app