# Running supervisord from the host, celery from a virtualenv (Django app)

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, supervisord

I'm trying to use celery and redis queue to perform a task for my Django app. Supervisord is installed on the host via `apt-get`, whereas celery resides in a specific virtualenv on my system, installed via `pip.

As a result, I can't seem to get the `celery` command to run via supervisord. If I run it from inside the virtualenv, it works fine, outside of it, it doesn't. How do I get it to run under my current set up? Is the solution simply to install `celery` via apt-get, instead of inside the virtualenv? Please advise.

My celery.conf inside /etc/supervisor/conf.d is:

```
[program:celery]
command=/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery -A /etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf -l info
directory = /home/mhb11/somefolder/myproject
environment=PATH="/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin",VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv",PYTHONPATH="/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7:/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
user=mhb11
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile = /etc/supervisor/logs/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile = /etc/supervisor/logs/celery-worker.log
autostart = true
autorestart = true
startsecs=10

stopwaitsecs = 600

killasgroup = true

priority = 998
```

And the folder structure for my Django project is:

```
/home/mhb11/somefolder/myproject
├── myproject
│   ├── celery.py       # The Celery app file
│   ├── __init__.py     # The project module file (modified)
│   ├── settings.py     # Including Celery settings
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── celerybeat-schedule
└── myapp
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tasks.py        # File containing tasks for this app
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

---

If I do a `status` check via supervisorctl, I get a FATAL error on the `command` I'm trying to run in celery.conf. Help!

p.s. note that user `mhb11` does not have root privileges, in case it matters. Moreover, `/etc/supervisor/logs/celery-worker.log` is empty. And inside `supervisord.log` the relevant error I see is `INFO spawnerr: can't find command '/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/‌​celery'`.

Comment: What happens when you run `/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery -A /etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf -l info` from terminal?

Comment: What does `/etc/supervisor/logs/celery-worker.log` have? What does `/var/log/supervisord.log` or `/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log` have?

Comment: @MuhammadTahir: `/etc/supervisor/logs/celery-worker.log` is empty. Inside `supervisord.log` the relevant error I see is `INFO spawnerr: can't find command '/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery'`.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir: I get `-bash: /home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/cel‌​ery: No such file or directory` if I try to run `/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/cel‌​ery -A /etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf -l info`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Path to celery binary is `myenv/bin/celery` whereas you are using `myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/cel‌‌​​ery`.

So if you try on your terminal the command you are passing to supervisor (command=xxx), you should get the same error.

You need to replace your `command=xxx` in your celery.conf with

```
command=/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/celery -A myproject.celery -l info
```

Note that I have also replaced `-A` parameter with celery app, instead of supervisor configuration. This celery app is relevant to your project directory set in `celery.conf` with

```
directory = /home/mhb11/somefolder/myproject
```

**On a side note**, if you are using Celery with Django, you can manage celery with Django's `manage.py`, no need to invoke celery directly. Like

```
python manage.py celery worker
python manage.py celery beat
```

For detail please read intro of Django Celery [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery).

Comment: Tahir, thanks for the response. I'll try it out and get back to you.

Comment: You're right. I overlooked this part of the documentation because I thought I need to access the installation folder of celery. Whereas I actually needed to access `/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/celery`, the folder where executable scripts are saved.

Comment: Django Celery is outdated now - 'Old django celery integration project.'